# ASP.NET MVC web hosting that has payment option of paypal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I already check some of asp.net mvc hosting sites listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637567/affordable-stable-asp-net-mvc-hosting-exist

I worry entering credit card number, all of them required credit card number.  Do you know which ASP.NET MVC web hosting that has paypal payment option?

Comment: I don't think Community Wiki tag is necessary here. :- )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to spring for a virtual private server I highly recommend [SoftSys Hosting](http://www.softsyshosting.com/Windows-VPS-HyperV.aspx).  They have a very reasonable $39/mo plan on which you can install all the necessary prerequisites for ASP.NET MVC or any other windows technology you want.

All this AND they accept Paypal via subscription or invoiced payments.

Comment: I also have a softsys account and they are great to work with.

Answer (score 2):

[Arvixe.com](http://www.arvixe.com/851-0-1-15.html)

they also use google checkout and a variety of other payment options.

Full disclosure = The link to Arvixe in my post is my affiliate link.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for ASP.NET MVC hosters with ecommerce software option?

You put the answer in your question, already. :-P

Go through the sites listed on your other StackOverflow reference question you listed and look at their features, do a little homework. Here's what I found in a few minutes (not comprehensive):

- **[Discount ASP.NET](http://www.discountasp.net/sp_componentone.aspx)** has a Component One option (ComponentOne is an [ecommerce ASP.NET software with PayPal option](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PayPaleCommerceASPNET/)).
- **Asp.Net Storefront** ([features here](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/t-features.aspx)) has MVC and a storefront that supports Paypal.

Comment: I think he is looking for a hosting provider that allows him to pay with paypal, not accept it on his site.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Station5.net](http://www.Station5.net) they are a good host and yes they do accept paypal. They also have an application vault for many open source projects. They do both Linux and Windows and support ASP.net MVC

Comment: This looks like a GoDaddy reseller account to me... Why not just buy directly from the source and cut out the middle man?

Comment: I did look at GoDaddy, but found Station5 a little cheaper. Plus when I called support I found them very helpful.